# How to locate radio buttons using the legend within the fieldset in selenium

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Trying to find a way to locate the radio buttons under a specific fiedlset legend. The webpage has 18 fieldsets with the only difference being the legend

```
<fieldset class="radio-group radio-standard">
   <legend>Legend example 1</legend>
   <ul class="rg-list">
      <li class="rg-item"><label class="radio-button"><input class="rb-input" type="radio" name="feature-12-0" value="none" checked=""><span aria-hidden="true" class="rb-design"></span><span class="rb-label">None</span></label></li>
      <li class="rg-item"><label class="radio-button"><input class="rb-input" type="radio" name="feature-12-0" value="RO"><span aria-hidden="true" class="rb-design"></span><span class="rb-label">Read Only</span></label></li>
      <li class="rg-item"><label class="radio-button"><input class="rb-input" type="radio" name="feature-12-0" value="RW"><span aria-hidden="true" class="rb-design"></span><span class="rb-label">Read/Write</span></label></li>
   </ul>
</fieldset>
```

I can locate the legend using this xpath:
`("//legend[contains(.,'Legend example 1')]`

Locating the "None" radio button using this xpath:
`//label[contains(.,'None')]/input");`

However I'm not too sure how to link the two to get to the radio buttons using the radio values.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried searching by the `rb-input` class or type rather than using the label?

Comment: `rb-input` is used widely throughout, so I don't think it would've recognised the specific radio button I was after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
//legend[.='Legend example 1']/following-sibling::ul//label[.='None']/input
```

Comment: Do you know what would be the best way to get the "checked" attribute back from the 'None' label? I've tried to grab it from the input class but then I lose the ability to extract it using the correctly label.

Comment: @user610 Selenium has built-in property for checking if input radio-button is checked. try `.isSelected()` method

Comment: I had to expand the xpath to be `//legend[.='Legend example 1']/following-sibling::ul//label[.='None']/input/..//span[@class='rb-label']` for it to locate properly and by using the `.isSelected()` it seems to return null as it's not finding the radio button specifically